# Update Teamcity Configuration parameter specification using REST API

Tags: rest, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I need to update the specification of a configuration parameter using Teamcity REST API.

[image]

Following the [REST documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-typedParamSpec) I tried a PUT request with the parameter value like:

```
http://teamcity:80/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/TestProject/parameters/TestProjectParam
```

But this updates the value of the parameter, however I need to udpate the specification of the parameter. I am using Teamcity 8.0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no way of validating if this works with TeamCity 8.0.6, but the following will create/update a parameter with spec in TeamCity 8.1.3.

**Request**

```
POST http://teamcity:80/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/TestProject/parameters/
```

**Headers**

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: YourToken
```

**Body**

```
<property name="TestProjectParam" value="" own="true">
  <type rawValue="select data_2='400' data_1='300' display='normal' data_3='500'" />
</property>
```

Comment: That's right I have realized the REST documentation says 8.1 only. I think in 8.0.6, only the value of parameter can be set, as I don't see rest of the properties even in a get request.